# Determine Browser Type

Tags: google-bigquery

First time using Google Big Query/Big Data. Still getting used to queries & commands, but i'm trying to count the total # of browsers that are using our application.

So far, I have:

```
SELECT 
  user_agent_data, session_count,
  SUM(LENGTH(user_agent_data)) as device_type
FROM [metal-filament-151915:ipc.intercomusers]
where 
  user_agent_data contains 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0'
group by user_agent_data, session_count
order by device_type DESC
```

Which is returning

```
[
  {
    "user_agent_data": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0",
    "session_count": "4",
    "device_type": "164"
  },
  {
    "user_agent_data": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0",
    "session_count": "2",
    "device_type": "164"
  }
]
```

This is counting *separate* instances of the same browser type. How would I be able to roll up that count as 2, instead of 2 separate rows from 2 separate users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need but does it work for you?

```
SELECT 
  user_agent_data,
  count(user_agent_data) freq_browsers
FROM [metal-filament-151915:ipc.intercomusers]
where 
  user_agent_data contains 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0'
group by user_agent_data, 
order by freq_browsers DESC
```

In your query, as you are grouping by the `session_count` field, the result will be separated by each value observed in session_count (in this case, the "2" and "4").

But still you would need the `count` operation to get how many browsers were observed (if I understood it correctly).

Comment: That did it! Thanks! Now this gives me the basis to pivot and figure out the rest.

Comment: If you are just getting started with BigQuery, I would suggest to work with [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) rather than legacy SQL if you can. We're in a transitional period--so legacy SQL is still the default--but standard SQL is the preferred dialect in BigQuery going forward.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Thanks for the tip! I've created an SQL 5.7 instance already. I've exported all data from Intercom, and i'm just sifting through it.

Comment: @Will Actually, i'm beating my head up over this. Now that I have 282 rows with all instances of the word "Firefox", I now simply want to roll up all 282 rows that have the keyword "Firefox" and "Windows" (for instance), and count that as say, "2918439" (or whatever the number might be).

Comment: @ocWavean Not sure if i'll be able to help you using this comment session, maybe it would be easier if you make another question showing us what you have tried so far and explaining in more details what you need. As far as I understood, you want something like `count(case when user_agent_data contains 'Firefox' and user_agent_data contains 'Windows' then 1 end)` but again, not sure if this solves well what you need.